# How to make a picture hover over others without moving the other pictures?

Tags: html, css

Originally, in my CSS, I have 4 images set together. 2 are on top, floated next to each other, and 2 are on the bottom.

```
.img1 {
    float: left;
}

.img2 {
    float: left;
}

.clear1 {
    clear: both;
}

.img3 {float: left;}
.img4 {float: left;}
.clear {clear: both;}
```

This is the basic idea of the code that I have for the 4 images to be next to each other, 2 on top, and 2 on the bottom. I want the first image, when I hover over it, to cover the other 3 images on the page. I know that to make the image hover, I have to do `.img1:hover {` followed by multiple attributes.

I am unaware on how to make the image cover the other 3 images, as it enlarges, without having the other 3 images move. If anyone knows how to do this, please help. When I just made `img1` larger, it pushed the other 3 images down, and I do not want that.

Other researched showed that using the `z-index` attribute might be helpful, but I am unaware on how to use it.

```
<div class="img1" >
</div>


<div class="img2" >
</div>


 <div class="img3" >
</div>


 <div class="img4" >
</div>
```

Comment: "I know that to make the image hover" - be careful there. The `:hover` pseudo-class is for applying different styles when your pointer (mouse cursor) is hovering over the element. It does not "make" the element itself hover.

Comment: Yes sorry, that is not exactly what I meant to say. I understand that, but I want the picture to cover the other 3, if possible. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Use position fixed on all the images and for hovered image use `z-index' and increase width and height

Comment: There's almost always a solution. You could try setting the position of the image to absolute and give it a width and height that covers the added dimensions of the others. You'll need to read up on `position: absolute`

Comment: That is a possibility. Thank you so much, but would it be possible for me to make any image hover over the others. If i wanted image 2 to cover the image 1,3, and 4, is that possible. I also want image 3 to cover the other 3, when the cursor hovers over it, and image 4 as well.

Comment: can you write your html so i can work on it

Comment: My html was 4 div tags with images in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/qncrsq8d/

```
.images{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.img1, .img3 {
    float: left;
    max-width:49%;
}

.img2, .img4 {
    float: right;
    max-width:49%;
}

.images img{
  max-width:100%;
}

.images img:hover{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  z-inedx:9;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the z-index value, you will first need to set a position property other than static. If you choose relative, then the images will move around as expected. Then, you can set the z-index of the image you want above the others to a higher number (the default is 0).

```
.img1, .img2, .img3, .img4 {
float:left; position: relative; }
.img1: hover {
z-index:10; }
```

Comment: So would this make image 1, cover image 2,3 and 4 without making them move? Is there a way for image 2 to be able to cover 1,3, and 4, when the cursor moves over it.

Comment: You would have to set a style on img2, img3, etc if you want them to act the same way. You may also have to add position: absolute to the image that hovers over the others.